# Usar arquivo js importado no html em uma aplicação ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com ES6 e fazendo o *build* com Webpack. Essa aplicação ficará em um template que já importa o jQuery via `<script src...></script>`.

Como eu faria para importar, a partir deste arquivo, o jQuery para usá-lo na minha aplicação? Já tentei usar o $ do jQuery na aplicação mas dá erro:

> `$ is not defined`

Mas eu não posso tirar essa importação do template pois ele é compartilhado por outas aplicações.

No HTML eu tenho o trecho de código a seguir:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Meu JavaScript:

```
class Products {
    constructor() {
        this.item = $('.prodcut-item')
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi,você quer usar `Jquery` dentro de um arquivo `ES6`, certo? Se for isso, como você está fazendo? Exemplifique para ficar mais fácil de lhe ajudar. Se possível, poste como está realizando a improtação do `Jquery`.

Comment: Talvez se mostrar seu código consigamos entender mais do que se você tentar explicar

Comment: `window.jQuery` deve funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, você deve instalar o jQuery via npm (ou Yarn):

```
npm install jquery
```

Aí no arquivo do JavaScript, você faz:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Então, seu arquivo final ficaria assim:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Products {
  constructor() {
    this.item = $('.prodcut-item')
  }
}
```

---

Lembrando que caso você fizer o que disse acima, você ainda poderá manter o `<script src></script>` no seu HTML.

Comment: eu não conseguiria, de alguma forma, usar esse jquery que importei no html sem ter que instalar via npm?

Comment: Como você está usando Webpack e ES6, não.